# Анализатор TCP/IP трафика

Tags: tcp-ip

Написал программу, которая посылает сообщения по TCP/IP. Но, что-то не работает. Нужен анализатор TCP/IP трафика. Есть ли какой нибудь хороший, небольшой и бесплатный?

Comment: @lightharut Не забывайте, пожалуйста, принимать ответы, если они отвечают на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: // вау, запилили новую фичу! Теперь ХэшКод может принимать ответы на вопросы?

Comment: @kirelagin Она была и раньше, но мы ей редко пользуемся: только когда очевидно, что вопрос реально отвечен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно есть! [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Редкостный баян :)

Comment: @cy6erGn0m В смысле??

Comment: В том смысле, что этот вопрос уже задавали.. и, кажется, даже не один раз

Comment: о_0 А я не видел… Может, не тут задавали, а на SO? ;)

Comment: Вот, например http://hashcode.ru/questions/1990/%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F